# Completely remove mssql linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, server, apt-get

Someone Help Please:
 My Ubuntu 14 Server has 1 GB Memory, Was trying installation but it didn't complete. It was a mistake but now I can't completely remove it. Any external package I try to install fails, such as 
(`apt-get install python-requests`) I get this error

(

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/mssql-server_14.0.800.90-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

)

Tried Uninstall but doesn't work

```
root@root: sudo apt-get remove mssql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc++1 libjemalloc1 libsss-nss-idmap0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mssql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 172 not upgraded.
184 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package mssql-server (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mssql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't wan't to lose my server

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the offending package before trying to remove it?

Comment: I tried but it requires a 3.5 GB memory and my ram is 1 GB. so it fails

Answer (score 1):

If other external packages are failing to install, try removing the **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list** file that you downloaded to register the Microsoft repository. Run `sudo apt-get update`. Then try installing the other external packages again and see if you have problems. This won't remove the failing mssql-server package, but maybe it will get you back and running with other packages.

Comment: I deleted the **mssql-server.list** did `sudo apt-get update` but still the packages are not installing. I get the following Error     
                                                                                    
`root@production:~# apt-get install httpie
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
                                                                                                                  E: The package mssql-server needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
root@production:~#`